# Flutter parsing error after correct response

Tags: flutter, dart, response, mapper, dio

Am a beginner in flutter development and am currently using dio for handling api calls. Currently the response is showing in the correct format after printing it. But in the parsing session I got error like this **"type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'"**

my model class

```
import 'package:object_mapper/object_mapper.dart';

class BottomNavListItem with Mappable {
int? id;
String? name;

@override
void mapping(Mapper map) {
map("id", id, (v) => id = v);
map("name", name, (v) => name = v);
}

}
```

response handling class

```
Future<List<BottomNavListItem>?> getFamilyStatus(String url) async {
Response response;
List<BottomNavListItem>? bottomNavListModel;
try {
response = await WebUtil.createDio().get(url);
if (kDebugMode) {
print(response.data.toString());
}
bottomNavListModel =
Mapper.fromJson(response.data).toObject<List<BottomNavListItem>>();
} on DioError catch (e) {
```

print(response.data.toString()); will prints :
**[{id: 1, name: test}, {id: 2, name: MiddleClass}, {id: 3, name: UpperMiddleClass}, {id: 4, name: Rich}]**
which is Json Array in correct format.
Anybody knows a solution pls help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to parse the data like this

```
 response.data.forEach((item){
      bottomNavListModel?.add(BottomNavListItem.fromJson(item));
    });
```

and update model like this...

```
class BottomNavListItem with Mappable {
  int? id;
  String? name;

  @override
  void mapping(Mapper map) {
    map("id", id, (v) => id = v);
    map("name", name, (v) => name = v);
  }

  BottomNavListItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The result that you got from the Dio is a List of Maps (not a Map), which may be a List<Map<String, dynamic>>.

You need to convert each of its items to `BottomNavListItem` with something like this:

```dart
List<BottomNavListItem>? bottomNavListModel;

bottomNavListModel = response.data
    .map((e) => Mapper.fromJson(e).toObject<BottomNavListItem>()!)
    .toList();
```

Comment: this returns "type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'"

Comment: @SaniyoMathew The issue said that the `response.data` is already a `List`, so you don't need to use `jsonDecode`. I edited the post.

Comment: this returns type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<BottomNavListItem>?'

Comment: @SaniyoMathew You can try the above code if you still want to use the `Mapper.fromJson`. I already tested it.

Answer (score 1):

The response that you are getting is list of a Map

So you can't do Mapper.fromJson(response.data) directly on response .

You can instead iterate through each item and call `Mapper.fromJson(response[i].data)` may this will help.

or to debug more easily you can try to find out runTimeType of your response
by using `print(response.runTimeType)`

Comment: I will do this perfectly with Iteration. But my architect says its not a perfect way.